# Heroku Modules Cannot be Found

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have trouble deploying my node express app on Heroku. It deployed successfully but the app failed to show. When I did Heroku log --tail. It showed me the following. I tried

> npm install

but didn’t work. Before this deployment, it worked with deployment with my branch. Then I merged to main branch then it failed the deployment.

The second image shows the directory. I noticed there's an extra folder "server" there due to the merge. What I wanted is to merge latest commits from master to main without this folder.

Originally on main branch before merge, there was just "client" and "server" folder with all files inside. Due to Heroku deployment requirement, I decided to take out all files from "server" folder to the root directory. But I guess it merged incorrectly. What's the best to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you remove, rename or move the `ExpressError` file? According to the require stack, it's attempting to find `/app/middleware/ExpressError`. Try running the project locally - it's possible that the merge has broken the build.

Comment: Locally, it worked normally. I didn't see merge conflicts in that file. I never modified that file in any commits except when I upload it. But I remember I moved it to the root directory before merging. But I see it's in the correct place on github "main" branch.

Comment: If you look at the main branch, is the file under `/app/middleware`?

Comment: I just updated the post. Do you think I should simply git remove this server folder? What's the best practice for merging to prevent it from happening again when dealing with merging with two branches with structural differences?

Comment: Try requiring `../expressError` instead of `../ExpressError`.